# make a div inside a div

Tags: html, css

I've the below html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="margins">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .main {
            width: 900px;
            height: 320px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            position:relative;
        }

        .margins {
            padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;

        }

        .top_H {
            width: 720px;
            height: 80px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .mid {
            display: inline-block;
            clear: both;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .mid_L {
            width: 200px;
            height: 120px;
            float: left;
            margin-right:10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .mid_C {
            width: 200px;
            height: 120px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-right:10px;
        }

        .mid_R {
            width: 200px;
            height: 120px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .bot {
            display: inline-block;
            clear: both;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .bot_L {
            width: 450px;
            height: 80px;
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .bot_R {
            width: 200px;
            height: 80px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="margins">
        <div class="top_H"></div>
            <div class="mid">
         <div class="mid_L"></div>
        <div class="mid_C"></div>
        <div class="mid_R"></div>
                </div>
            <div class="bot">
        <div class="bot_L"></div>
        <div class="bot_R""></div>
                </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here i am trying to create a container div(margins) inside the main div, with the gap of 10 px on each side, but when i view it in web browser it is overlapped. please let me know where am i going wrong.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/V9N3u/) is the fiddle.

Thanks

Comment: You have `height` defined, what do you expect?

Comment: your height .main{ height:320px;} is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse it is overlapping. in your .main class you have set a height, and it's not high enough. also, if you want to be absolutely sure that nothing goes over your div, set an overflow in the css !

Answer (score 0):

make height of main div auto :

```
 .main {
            width: 900px;
            height: auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
            position:relative;
        }
```

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/V9N3u/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Now define** your `.main` `min-height` and **remove** `height`

as like this

```
.main {
            height: 320px; // remove this
            min-height: 320px;  // add this
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

min-height for .main class

```
.main {
        width: 900px;
        min-height: 320px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        position:relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The others are right about the `height`.

You may also want to remove the `margin-bottom` of `.bot` to get rid of the extra spacing (unless that's on purpose):

```
.bot {
        display: inline-block;
        clear: both; 
        margin-bottom: 10px; //remove
        border: 1px solid black;
     }
```

And you also have one too many `"` in your html:

```
<body>
...
    <div class="bot_R""></div>
```